# Nested schema with map field is not working with mongoose and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I’m pretty new to using Mongoose and can’t seem to find a fix. I have two schema’s; postSchema, commentSchema. The first one is for a post and the second is for comments that are stored within the post. Both schema’s have a map field to store likes. The post likes field’s setter and getter work when I try to update but when I try to do the same for the comments it gives me an error that the set or get is not a function. When I check if the likes are an instance of a map, the post likes will return true, while the comments like will return false. If anyone could help or direct me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I'm working with. When I create a comment to add to a post, the comment.likes checks as a Map. After I update the post I make a call to get all the post's and I rechecked that the comment.likes is a Map, but now it turns out false.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    picturePath: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Map,
      of: Boolean,
      default: new Map(),
    },
    comments: {
      type: Array,
      default: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
export default Post;
```

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    postId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    picturePath: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Map,
      of: Boolean,
      default: new Map(),
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
export default Comment;
```

```js
export const addComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { userId, picturePath, description } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const newComment = new Comment({
      id,
      userId,
      userName: user.userName,
      picturePath,
      //likes: {},
      description,
    });
    newComment.set('likes', new Map());

    console.log(newComment.likes instanceof Map);
    const upDatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { $push: { comments: newComment } },
      { new: true }
    );

    const allPost = await Post.find();
    console.log(allPost[0].comments[2].likes instanceof Map);
    res.status(200).json(allPost);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err');
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

This works for the post.likes.

```js
export const likePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { userId } = req.body;
    const post = await Post.findById(id);
    const isLiked = post.likes.get(userId);

    if (isLiked) {
      post.likes.delete(userId);
    } else {
      post.likes.set(userId, true);
    }

    const upDatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { likes: post.likes },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.status(200).json(upDatedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

This doesn’t work. When I check if element.likes is an instanceOf Map it gives back false, but for post.likes it returns true. Updated with the console.log's.

```js
export const likeComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { postId, userId } = req.body;
    let post = await Post.findById(postId);
    let comments = post.comments;
    console.log('comments: ', comments);
    console.log('likes: ', comments[0].likes);
    console.log(
      'Is likes an instanceof Map: ',
      post.comments[0].likes instanceof Map
    );
    //comments[0].likes.set(userId, true);
    //post.comments[0].set('likes', new Map());
    //console.log(comments[6].likes);
    // comments.forEach((element) => {
    //   if (element._id.toString() === id) {
    //     element.likes.set(userId, true);
    //   }
    // });

    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Here is the output fro the console.log's.

```
comments:  [
  {
    userId: '63dc0274bd8c03b1e417cfc4',
    userName: 'dummyUserThree',
    picturePath: '',
    description: 'Likes still not working',
    _id: new ObjectId("63e13f26603a052fc8f16b09"),
    likes: {}
  }
]
likes:  {}
Is likes an instanceof Map:  false
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(comments)` in the `likeComment` handler, and add that to the question?

Comment: I added the console.log(comments), along with the output. Any help would be awesome.